# HackerRank Lower Bound-STL

Tags: c++, beginner, programming-challenge, time-limit-exceeded

This is still my first week of learning C++, I solved the *lower bound STL* challenge in [HackerRank Lower Bound STL](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/cpp-lower-bound/copy-from/32084764) but I'm having time exceeded issue for long input. I'm open to constructive criticism, ways to improve in terms of syntax, style and performance.

> You are given \$N\$ integers in the sorted order. Then you are given
> \$Q\$ queries. In each query, you will be given an integer and you have
> to tell whether that integer is present in the array if so you have
> to tell at which index it is present and if it is not present you have
> to tell the index at which the smallest integer that is just greater
> than the given number is present. Lower bound is a function that can
> be used with a sorted vector.
>
> **Input Format**
>
> The first line of the input contains the number of integers \$N\$.
> The next line contains \$N\$ integers in sorted order. The next line
> contains \$Q\$, the number of queries. Then \$Q\$ lines follow each
> containing a single integer \$Y\$.
> **If the same number is present multiple times, you have to print the first index at which it occurs. The input is such that you always have
> an answer for each query.**
>
> **Constraints**
>
> - \$1 \leq N \leq 10^5\$
> - \$1 \leq X_i \leq 10^9\$, where \$X_i\$ is \$i^{th}\$ element in the    array
> - \$1 \leq Q \leq 10^5\$
> - \$1 \leq Y \leq 10^9\$
>
> **Output Format**
>
> For each query you have to print "Yes"(without the quotes) if the
> number is present and at which index it is present separated by a
> space. If the number is not present you have to print "No"(without the
> quotes) followed by the index of the next smallest number just greater
> than that number. You have to output each query in a new line.
>
> **Sample Input**
>
> ```
>  8
>  1 1 2 2 6 9 9 15
>  4
>  1
>  4
>  9
>  15
> ```
>
> **Sample Output**
>
> ```
>  Yes 1
>  No 5
>  Yes 6
>  Yes 8
> ```

Here is my code

```
#include <cmath>
#include <cstdio>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>



int main() {
    /* Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT */  
    int N;
    int query;
    int queryLength;
    {
        
    std::vector<int>::iterator low;
    std::vector<int>::iterator  foundValue;
    std::cin >> N;
    
    std::vector<int> v(N);
    //populate the vector
     for(int i =0; i<N; i++){
         std::cin >> v[i];
     }
        
    std::cin >> queryLength;
    
    for(int j = 0; j < queryLength; j++){
         std::cin >> query;
         foundValue= find(v.begin(), v.end(), query);
         if (foundValue != v.end())
         {
             std::cout << "Yes "<< (foundValue-v.begin()+ 1) << std::endl;
         }
          else{
            low = std::lower_bound (v.begin(), v.end(),query);
             std::cout << "No "<< find(v.begin(), v.end(), *low)-v.begin()+ 1 << std::endl;
          }
    }
}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why use find and lower_bound. `find()` is O(n) while `lower_bound()` is O(ln(n)). You can use `std::distance()` to find the index from two iterators.

Comment: I am pretty sure the values looking like 105 and 109, given as constraints, should be the fith and the ninth power of 10.

Comment: Suppose the **N** in _'Then N lines follow'_ should read **Q**...

Answer (score 7):

Although you've probably already solved this problem, I'll still post my review for completion's sake.

#### 1. Performance

Just as Loki said, you should use `std::lower_bound()` and `std::distance()` to solve this task, because `std::find()` has higher complexity.

#### 2. General tips

1. Do not `include` unused libraries (in this case, `<cmath>` and `<cstdio>`).
2. Only declare variables when you need them. Declaring all the variables at the beginning of the program is old C style practice, which is discouraged in C++.
3. Prefer prefix to postfix `operator++`. The postfix version creates a copy, so if you do not need that copy, you should use the prefix version.
4. If you have access to C++11, you should consider using `auto` more. It'll make your code easier to read and save you some typing.
5. You can safely omit `return 0` from `main()`;

> [C++11: 3.6.1/5]: A return statement in `main` has the effect of leaving the `main` function (destroying any objects with automatic storage duration) and calling `std::exit` with the return value as the argument. If control reaches the end of `main` without encountering a `return` statement, the effect is that of executing `return 0;`.

6. Give your variables better names. Although other variable names in your code are good, a `vector` named `v` is not very descriptive.
7. Use `const_iterator`s for functions that do not alter the original range.

#### 3. Final code

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

int main() {
    int N;
    std::cin >> N;
    
    std::vector<int> numbers(N);
    //populate the vector
     for(int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
         std::cin >> numbers[i];
     }
    
    int queryLength;
    std::cin >> queryLength;    

    for(int j = 0; j < queryLength; ++j) {
        int query;
        std::cin >> query;
        auto lowerBoundIt = std::lower_bound(numbers.cbegin(), numbers.cend(), query);
        if(*lowerBoundIt == query) {
            std::cout << "Yes ";
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "No ";
        }
        std::cout << std::distance(numbers.cbegin(), lowerBoundIt) + 1 << '\n';
    }
}
```

Comment: A further improvement could be to use the previously-found result to narrow the search to one side or the other - the gain is probably not worth the complexity, though.

Answer (score 3):

You've created an unnecessary scope by putting braces after `int querylength`.  Do you have a good reason for doing this?